# Can one sell Chametz he doesn't know about?

Tags: halacha, passover, selling-mechirat-chametz

If one sold his Chometz in his house for Pesach, and then found (on Pesach) some old Chometz food lying around, does he have to burn it? He probably didn't have it in mind during the sale, but on the other hand the contract says that all Chometz in his house is sold.

Comment: Or was it rendered owner-less when you said "that I know about or do not know about" before Pesach?  If you find an owner-less object, can you now claim it as yours (assuming you found it after Pesach)?

Comment: The person to ask is the actual Rabbi through whom you sold your chametz. What matters is the wording of the actual contract.

Comment: ShmuelBrin, please see @Mike's comment, above. Did you (as I suspect) mean the _chametz_ was found on _Pesach_? If so, can you please [edit] that in to the question for clarity's sake?